# Starting subprocesses in racket

Tags: command-line, scheme, racket

I would like to start n subprocesses from within Dr Racket or from the command line (i.e. I would like to run the code either entirely within the Dr Racket ide or entirely from the command line).

These processes would then exchange messages through stdin and stdout.

Is this possible by modifying the following code, which starts them from the cmd line? (or is it possible at all? Note that I am a scheme beginner)

```
(struct proc (stdout stdin))

(define (start-program p)
  (define-values (s stdout stdin stderr) (subprocess #f #f #f p))
  (thread (lambda () (copy-port stderr (current-error-port))))
  (proc stdout stdin))

(define programs (vector->list (current-command-line-arguments)))

(map start-program programs)

(define (send-to proc v)
   (write v (proc-stdin proc))
   (flush-output (proc-stdin proc)))

(define (receive-from proc)
  (read (proc-stdout proc)))
```

Comment: While intuitive, I doubt things work like that ;p (If it actually does, WOW!) Edit: Say your producer worked, where is your consumer code?

Comment: Yes it works from the command line (I tested it). Very neat indeed.

Comment: I added code to read and write to a subprocess

Comment: So if it works, what is that question? :D Or did you find the solution now? (If so, please post it as answer for future reference)

Comment: The question is how do I do the same thing from within Dr racket (not just from the command line). I.e the code works from the command line but not from within Dr Racket.

Comment: You should probably clarify that you want it to do both (not just 'or') in that case. It would probably need someone with good knowledge how DrRacket works. I suggest you ask (and refer here) on the FreeNode #racket IRC channel.

Comment: Do you have a concrete example that is not working properly?

Comment: To work from within DrRacket I would have to set current-command-line-arguments from within DrRacket and I dont know how or if it is possible.

Comment: Attempted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you're after, but `current-command-line-arguments` is a parameter so you can set it with `parameterize`.

Here's an adaptation of your code that produces the files in the current directory:

```
#lang racket
(struct proc (stdout stdin))

(define (start-program p)
  (define-values (s stdout stdin stderr) (subprocess #f #f #f p))
  (thread (lambda () (copy-port stderr (current-error-port))))
  (proc stdout stdin))

(define (send-to proc v)
   (write v (proc-stdin proc))
   (flush-output (proc-stdin proc)))

(define (receive-from proc)
  (read (proc-stdout proc)))

(parameterize ([current-command-line-arguments (vector "ls")])
  (define programs
    (map find-executable-path (vector->list (current-command-line-arguments))))
  (define running-programs
    (map start-program programs))
  (let loop ([x (receive-from (first running-programs))])
    (displayln x)
    (unless (eof-object? x)
      (loop (receive-from (first running-programs))))))
```

Btw, DrRacket is just the name of the IDE. Racket is the name of the language.